# Getting unique item pairs in XML file using python

Tags: python, xml, pandas, csv, numpy

I have an XML dataset that is designed like this:

```
<DataSet>
    <Record><!-- each DataSet can have zero to many Record tags -->
        <Identifier><!-- each Record will definitely have exactly one Identifier tag -->
            <MRN value="MRN"></MRN><!-- Each Identifier will have zero or at the most one MRN tag, with alphanumeric character as the patient's MRN in value attribute -->
        </Identifier>
        <Medication><!-- each Record will definitely have exactly one Medication tag -->
            <Item value="CUI"></Item><!-- Each Medication will have zero to many Item tags, with alphanumeric character as the Medication CUI in the value attribute -->
        </Medication>
    </Record>
</DataSet>
```

And I want to export a list of unique pairs of MRN values/CUI values into a csv file. The final CSV file would look something like these two columns:

[image]

If an MRN has more than one CUI, then I want the MRN value to repeat on the first column for each CUI. Also, I do not want any empty values, meaning I don't want to extract any MRNs that don't have any CUIs or viceversa.

I have tried working with lists and dictionaries, but the problem is I can't get the final output to look like I want, with the MRN value repeating for each CUI. I have even created a dataframe to see which CUI belongs to which MRN, but again that is not the output I want. Here is the code I have used:

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('/med/dataset.xml')
root = tree.getroot()


mrn = []
cui = []
for element in root:
    for item in element[0::2]:
        d=[]
        mrn.append(d)
        for child in item:
            d.append(child.attrib['value'])
    for item in element[1::2]:
        d=[]
        cui.append(d)
        for child in item:
            d.append(child.attrib['value'])
new_list = [a + b for a,b in zip(mrn, cui)]
print(new_list)
df = pd.DataFrame(new_list)
print(df)
```

I want to be able to do this using only standard Python libraries (pandas, numpy, xml.etree.ElementTree, and csv).

Any ideas?

Comment: You may use beautifulsoup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ElementTree to parse the XML, store the mrn/cui combos in a set, and then create the csv with csv.

Here's an example...

**XML Input** (dataset.xml)

```xml
<DataSet>
    <Record>
        <Identifier>
            <MRN value="MRN1"></MRN>
        </Identifier>
        <Medication>
            <Item value="CUI1"></Item>
            <Item value="CUI2"></Item>
            <Item value="CUI3"></Item>
        </Medication>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <Identifier>
            <MRN value="MRN1"></MRN>
        </Identifier>
        <Medication>
            <Item value="CUI1"></Item>
            <Item value="CUI2"></Item>
            <Item value="CUI3"></Item>
        </Medication>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <Identifier>
            <MRN value="MRN2"></MRN>
        </Identifier>
        <Medication>
            <Item value="CUI1"></Item>
            <Item value="CUI2"></Item>
            <Item value="CUI3"></Item>
        </Medication>
    </Record>
</DataSet>
```

**Python**

```py
import csv
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("dataset.xml")

mrn_cui = set()

for record in tree.findall(".//Record"):
    mrn = record.find("./Identifier/MRN")
    items = record.findall("./Medication/Item")
    if mrn is not None and items:
        for cui in items:
            mrn_cui.add(f"{mrn.attrib['value']}|{cui.attrib['value']}")

with open("test.csv", "w", newline="") as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=",", quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    csvwriter.writerow(["MRN", "CUI"])
    for entry in sorted(mrn_cui):
        csvwriter.writerow(entry.split('|'))
```

**Output** (test.csv)

```
MRN,CUI
MRN1,CUI1
MRN1,CUI2
MRN1,CUI3
MRN2,CUI1
MRN2,CUI2
MRN2,CUI3
```

You could also simplify it a little by using lxml instead of ElementTree...

**Python**

```py
import csv
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("dataset.xml")

mrn_cui = set()

for record in tree.xpath(".//Record[Identifier/MRN/@value and Medication/Item/@value]"):
    mrn = record.xpath("./Identifier/MRN/@value")
    for cui in record.xpath("./Medication/Item/@value"):
        mrn_cui.add(f"{mrn[0]}|{cui}")

with open("test.csv", "w", newline="") as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=",", quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    csvwriter.writerow(["MRN", "CUI"])
    for entry in sorted(mrn_cui):
        csvwriter.writerow(entry.split('|'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop over your medications inside your loop over MRNs. Try something like this.

```
mrn_li = []
cui_li = []
for record in root:
    for mrn in record[0]:
        for med in record[1]:
            mrn_li.append(mrn.attrib['value'])
            cui_li.append(med.attrib['value'])

new_list = [[i, j] for i, j in zip(mrn_li,cui_li)]
print new_list
```